# creating Pivot table in excel sheet using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

How to set header caption in pivot table using java.
I have to create pivot table in excel sheet using apache poi.Now to change row and column header label using java.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
public class readxlsx {  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                /* Read the input file that contains the data to pivot */
                FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("inputFile.xlsx"));    
                /* Create a POI XSSFWorkbook Object from the input file */
                XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
                /* Read Data to be Pivoted - we have only one worksheet */
                XSSFSheet sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
                /* Get the reference for Pivot Data */
                AreaReference a=new AreaReference("A1:C51");
                /* Find out where the Pivot Table needs to be placed */
                CellReference b=new CellReference("I5");
                /* Create Pivot Table */
                XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(a,b);
                /* Add filters */
                pivotTable.addReportFilter(0);
                pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
                pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2); 
                /* Write Pivot Table to File */
                FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("POI_XLS_Pivot_Example.xlsx")); 
                my_xlsx_workbook.write(output_file);
                input_document.close(); 
        }
}
```

This may help your issue.